# disable button using server side scripting

Tags: php, paypal

I have completed my PayPal integration using IPN and PDT everything is working fine.

But I have a problem with the disabled button on completed status.

```
<input type = "submit" disabled = "
    <?php

    $adminid = '35';
    $res_completed_status = $conn->query("select * from payments where user_id = '$adminid'");

        if ($res_completed_status->num_rows > 0) { echo 'disabled'; } 
        else { echo ''; }

    ?>" class="btn btn-sucess"  />
```

Here in it, I write `disabled="disabled"` then it's disabled it's working but if a user removes `disabled="disabled"` from inspect element of Mozilla then it's enabled so is there any way of disabling button using server side coding. Or any other way to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Place an image instead of the SUBMIT button, or simply BUTTON element.

Comment: then the problem is same brother how can i disable image or submit button through server side scripting ?

Comment: what is `action` of the form ? This check should be at server side. i.e when  that page is accessed check if admin is logged in. If it's not admin, don't display button at all. And write a text somewhere, payment can be made by admin only.

Comment: @Bhavin show <button> element. And to be sure change FORM ACTION to another URL.

Comment: You must always perform validation on form submit or on button action. Is user authenticated for this action? If yes then perform action or restrict. So in your case the validation you are performing to disable the button, then you should check similarly on that button action.

Comment: form action is <?php echo $paypal_url; ?>. where $paypal_url is url of sandbox account.  if i checked it with admin logged in session then brother how can i figured out that payment is completed or not because after insertion of data i select the res of data and checked that if payment completed and data is inserted properly then only completed button.

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar. brother how can i check on form action that paypal's transaction is completed or not ? Insertion is occured on completion of transaction and after that i can figured it out that completed or not. plz tell me if my process is wrong

Comment: @Bhavin Then I would suggest, if condition returns true then only show button or else show only text. No need to show disabled button, disabled button performs nothing.

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar. yeah brother that's the answer what i needed. thank you for your precious time :)

Comment: You're welcome Bro! I've added my answer below, please upvote and accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this,

```
<?php

$adminid = '35';

$res_completed_status = $conn->query("select * from payments where user_id = '$adminid'");

if ($res_completed_status->num_rows > 0) { echo '{text you want show}'; } 

else { ?> <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-sucess" /> <?php } ?>
```